# Reinstall MySql but keep database tables and data

Tags: mysql, backup, installation

Please help!

There are server issues and MySql is no longer running on our server (Ubuntu).  The service is not recognized and needs to be reinstalled.  Unfortunately, the database has not been backed up for 48 hours and that is a lot of information.

**How do I reinstall MySql AND keep all my database data?**  Please note - I can't access mysql at all.  I can't use command line mysql nor phpmyadmin.

Thanks in advance and let me know if I am missing important details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the database files are accessible, you can follow these steps:

1. `mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql.bkp`
2. `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`
3. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
4. `mv /var/lib/mysql.bkp /var/lib/mysql`
5. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

It should work if you don't have any table file corruption.